# Angular + Chrome - Two tabs of the same app freeze both HTTP queries

Tags: angular

We are on a very wierd bug, and can't identify if it comes from the app configuration, the Apache configuration or from Chrome (impossible to use another browser here to test).

Loading the first app works fine, then opening a second tab freeze all new backend queries to a `pending` limbo forever. No logs are triggered in backend.

[image]

Whenever one of the tabs are closed, the other one unlocks immediately and all pending queries are executed and completed.

Note that this problem does not occurs with `ng serve`, only when deployed with `ng build --prod` to an Apache server.

What can be the cause ? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar once when doing XHR polling requests. In fact, I see you are using Google Chrome. A limit of 6 connection is applied by the navigator.

You might be switching to Websocket protocol in order to solve you issue since there is no connection limit to the same origin with this.

Since you didn't give us more details, all of this is hypothetical but your problem remind me of this...

Comment: In fact you were right. We have 3 SockJS connections gracefully degraded to long polling, and it seems those  counts in the Chrome limit you mention. We reduced the numbers of sockets and this is now unfrozen. Thanks !